# Sony QX10 - Remote API SDK

Tags: c++, camera, sony

Is it possible to control the Sony QX10/100, using the Sony’s Camera Remote API SDK from C++ Windows program?

Thank you for your patience and time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible.  See https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/ for more details.

Comment: Hi Marlin, I am currently developing c++ drivers for the remote camera api. I have put it online on github, can you confirm that it is ok licence-wise? https://github.com/ernest-galbrun/sony_remote_camera_cpp_drivers/tree/dev

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on this related other question, maybe you would want to check it out ?

[Windows compatibility with the Sony Camera Remote API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340286/windows-compatibility-with-the-sony-camera-remote-api)

Answer (score 0):

The API works with any device on any OS and programming language, it's just http calls and camera discovery needs some basic socket listening. Though to make it easy to connect to the camera, the device you're connecting from, should support Wi-Fi Direct : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct

The problem is that these APIs are incredibly simplistic. No way to transfer/delete images off the memory card, can't take pictures without a memory card, can't add a custom streaming service, (only USTERAM is supported), the device doesn't have an 'always on' mode so you need to physically walk up and turn-on/reset (for cameras where this makes sense like the AS100V). It's like Sony has one guy in the basement working on this.