# Sony Camera API Wifi, is it possible to connect the camera as a wifi client to an access point?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

The device that will act as the remote-control(Ipad) for the camera (QX10) has to be connected to the internet to upload or sync photos as they are taken from the remote camera. The challenge is that the ipad has to connect to the QX10 as a client. Is is possible to have the QX10 and ipad connect to the same access point and they would still communicate? so ideally can the QX10 be a client and not the access point on the network?

Comment: Also possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478469/sony-qx10-remote-api-sdk - tldr - You could probably put something together using the Sony’s Camera Remote API SDK. https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Sony QX1 the device is only able to act as a WiFi access point, there is no (publicly documented) capability to make it a client. I'd be staggered if the QX10 was any different.

Comment: Making it a client (whilst techinically possible) isn't needed - one can access all the data require over via HTTP using the API - good examples here - https://chdk.setepontos.com/index.php?topic=10736.0